# docker run --env-file /path/to/file.env fails with "no such file or directory"

Tags: docker, file-not-found, docker-run, env-file

I'm trying to run a docker image on a Debian server. The preproduced image has been pulled from Docker Hub.

The cmd line is (stripped to the bones):

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8190:433 --env-file /path/to/file.env my-image
```

/path/to/file.env is similiar to /var/lib/myapp/data/file.env

Executing this results in an error message:

```
docker: open /path/to/file.env: no such file or directory
```

But: the file exists (`ls /path/to/file.env` shows the file). Tried also chown to root and chmod 777 wthout success. Tried also copying the file to /tmp and referring to this file.

Comment: That should be `--env-file`. Is that a typo in your question?

Comment: thx: it's a typo in the question, I will fix it

Comment: By any chance you installed docker via snap? If yes, it can't access any files outside of `$HOME` directory (see https://snapcraft.io/install/docker/debian)

Comment: I didn't set up the server (was done by an external company), Is there a way to detect whether Docker was set up via snap?

Comment: `snap list` did it, and yes, it has been installed via snap. Thank you! Saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

Let me copy comment from [derpirscher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776927/derpirscher) here.

> By any chance you installed docker via snap? If yes, it can't access any files outside of $HOME directory (see snapcraft.io/install/docker/debian)

say if you move file to

> /root/snap/file.env

then run

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8190:433 --env-file /root/snap/file.env my-image
```

Comment: Hi @Jirapong, thx. I uninstalled Docker as snap and installed it as recommended by Docker. Now everything is working as expected.

Comment: @Recurs1on Thank you for confirmation. Can you mark this as answer?